# Symfony 1.3.6 - javascript popup windw - how?

Tags: php, javascript, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am using SF 1.3.6. I have some static text files (HTML) that I want to be able to display in a popup window.

I tried this:

```
<a href="javascript:showPopup('foobar.html', 'all about foobar')">foobar</a><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
function showPopup(url, title) {  window.open(url,title,"menubar=no,width=430,height=360,toolbar=no");} 
</script>
```

I get an sf404Exception when I click on the link. How may I fix this?

Note: I dont really want to write a route, and action and a template for these static files - is there another way to achieve popups with SF?

**[Edit]**

This is my original .htaccess content.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  #force everything to www so URLs look the same
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  #redirect on trailing slash (otherwise, Symfony will 404)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I replaced it with Jeremy's script. I then restarted Apache but I am getting the same error

> 404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
>   Empty module and/or action after
>   parsing the URL "/foobar.html" (/).

Comment: Is foobar.html at the top-level of the web folder?

Comment: yes the file location is like: web/foobar.html

Answer (score 1):

The default Symfony .htaccess file should have a line to serve files that already exist in the web directory. Make sure that the path your specifying for the file exists inside of web. Here's the relevant lines from .htaccess:

```
# we check if the .html version is here (caching)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Here's my full .htaccess with some other improvements:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  #force everything to www so URLs look the same
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  #redirect on trailing slash (otherwise, Symfony will 404)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a leading "/" to foobar.html.

```
javascript:showPopup('/foobar.html', 'all about foobar')
```

If you're in a dev environment, then calling foobar.html would actually be calling `frontend_dev.php/foobar.html`. Adding the leading "/" strips out the frontend_dev.php.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you store your static files? To access them with */foobar.html* you need to put 'em in the *web/* directory.

Also, remember to make them readable by the web server.

Comment: Hi Kuba: my files are in the web folder and they are readable by all (mode: 644)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a symfony problem nor .htaccess problem. I just tested it with a default .htaccess on vanilla symfony project and it simply works (permissings 644). Do you have your host configured as adviced in symfony docs?